# Why can't normal single-use alkaline batteries be recharged?

Tags: battery-charging

What is the electrical/chemical mechanism that prevents them from being recharged? If recharging is possible in a narrow circumstance, what are the constraints and drawbacks?

Comment: One problem with at least some types of primary-cell chemistry (and to a lesser extent with some rechargeable ones) is that draining the cell will erode away one of the electrodes; forcing current into the cell will deposit material back onto the electrode, *but not necessarily in the same place as that from which it was eroded*.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/can-you-recharge-non-rechargeable-alkaline-batteries

Comment: Yeah, I just added an answer there after doing some of my own research. However, I'd love to get some authoritative input from a chemist or electrical engineer.